# Create table and insert data in local storage of Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can anyone please explain how to create a table and insert data in to the table in local storage for Chrome extensions? I need to retrieve the values from the table and do some validation.

Comment: What do you mean by table? As in HTML table with rows & columns? Please be more specific and provide an example of data you want to be stored.

Comment: i want to store list of merchants in one table named merchants and list of products in other table named products

Answer (score 0):

You can JSON.stringify() your table and then when you need it JSON.parse() it again.

Example:

```
var table = [  { name : "Tom" , zip : 8210 } , { name : "Bob" , zip : 8201 } ];

localStorage.table = JSON.stringify( table );

console.log( localStorage.table ); //For the curious folks ( assuming Chrome here )

var retrievedTable = JSON.parse( localStorage.table ); 

console.log( retrievedTable );
```

Of course you would need some asserts there, you dont want to blindly parse localStorage data.

T.

Comment: thanks tom.. but i'm bit confuse that how the extension would create a connection with local storage..i had worked on firefox addon and for creating table we used to create connection using mozilla storage service

Comment: Ashwin, all you need to do is use localStorage, see this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage